# How to extend Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUser<TKey>

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

I am trying to implement a registration prozess with email confirmation for my web application. I am using a IdentityServer3.AspNetIdentity service.

```
public class AspNetIdentityUserService<TUser, TKey> : UserServiceBase
    where TUser : class, Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUser<TKey>, new()
    where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
{
```

My problem is the **TUser** which required the **Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUser** interface. In my implemented function the incoming user context is the right one but I do not have access to all attributes which you can see in the following two images.

[image]

[image]

http://img5.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/b6aa42c662dd1kv063h4g5p.png
http://img5.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/d75b1e6462dd1wi9clqj6e7.png

Do you know how can I extend the Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUser to the effect that I have access to the attributes Lastname and Firstname?

Comment: You should create your own user class and pass that as the type parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Here `TUser` is a custom implemented class in `IdentityServer3` which is inherited from `IdentityUser` for user identity.

You are not able to access these properties because TUser is object of `IdentityServer3.Host.WebHost.AspId.User` represented by base class `IdentityUser` or `IUser`.

The Quickwatch would show the object properties but it wouldn't appear in intellisense.

You need to cast the `TUser` to `IdentityServer3.Host.WebHost.AspId.User`.

```
var user = new TUser() as IdentityServer3.Host.WebHost.AspId.User;
user.FirstName = "Tester";
user.LastName = "Doer";
```

This should give you the workaround.